# Speedometer Animation Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I have 8 images which are placed circularly on the dial which resembles a speedometer with first image placed at the position which is similar to 0 and the last image on the position similar to 200 or the last value of the speedometer.
Now i want to rotate the needle which is fixed at the base and moves from the first image to last.While the needle rotates,as it moves over the images,the images changes.
The needle moves from first image to the last and moves back to first image.!
Have removed the sensor's code as i didnt wanted and remove the background and major chunk added a new method called `reverse()` for reversing the movement not able to find where i am going wrong. it just execute the loop once and comes out.

```
public final class Thermometer extends View  
{
    private static final String TAG = Thermometer.class.getSimpleName();
    private Handler handler;

    // drawing tools

    private Paint scalePaint;
    private RectF scaleRect;


    private Paint logoPaint;
    private Bitmap logo;
    private Matrix logoMatrix;
    private float logoScale;

    private Paint handPaint;
    private Path handPath;
    private Paint handScrewPaint;

    private Paint backgroundPaint;
    // end drawing tools

    private Bitmap background; // holds the cached static part

    // scale configuration
    private static final int totalNicks = 100;
    private static final float degreesPerNick = 360.0f / totalNicks;
    private static final int centerDegree = 40; // the one in the top center (12
                                                // o'clock)
    private static final int minDegrees = -30;
    private static final int maxDegrees = 110;

    // hand dynamics -- all are angular expressed in F degrees
    private boolean handInitialized = false;
    private float handPosition = minDegrees;
    private float handTarget = minDegrees;
    private float handVelocity = 0.0f;
    private float handAcceleration = 0.0f;
    private long lastHandMoveTime = -1L;

    public Thermometer(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public Thermometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public Thermometer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) 
    {
        Bundle bundle = (Bundle) state;
        Parcelable superState = bundle.getParcelable("superState");
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(superState);

        handInitialized = bundle.getBoolean("handInitialized");
        handPosition = bundle.getFloat("handPosition");
        handTarget = bundle.getFloat("handTarget");
        handVelocity = bundle.getFloat("handVelocity");
        handAcceleration = bundle.getFloat("handAcceleration");
        lastHandMoveTime = bundle.getLong("lastHandMoveTime");
    }

    @Override
    protected Parcelable onSaveInstanceState() 
    {
        Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

        Bundle state = new Bundle();
        state.putParcelable("superState", superState);
        state.putBoolean("handInitialized", handInitialized);
        state.putFloat("handPosition", handPosition);
        state.putFloat("handTarget", handTarget);
        state.putFloat("handVelocity", handVelocity);
        state.putFloat("handAcceleration", handAcceleration);
        state.putLong("lastHandMoveTime", lastHandMoveTime);
        return state;
    }

    private void init() 
    {
        handler = new Handler();
        initDrawingTools();
    }


    private void initDrawingTools() 
    {
        // the linear gradient is a bit skewed for realism

        logoPaint = new Paint();
        logoPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),R.drawable.logo);
        logoMatrix = new Matrix();
        logoScale = (1.0f / logo.getWidth()) * 0.3f;

        logoMatrix.setScale(logoScale, logoScale);

        handPaint = new Paint();
        handPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        handPaint.setColor(0xff392f2c);
        handPaint.setShadowLayer(0.01f, -0.005f, -0.005f, 0x7f000000);
        handPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        handPath = new Path();
        handPath.moveTo(0.5f, 0.5f + 0.2f);
        handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.010f, 0.5f + 0.2f - 0.007f);
        handPath.lineTo(0.5f - 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
        handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.002f, 0.5f - 0.32f);
        handPath.lineTo(0.5f + 0.010f, 0.5f + 0.2f - 0.007f);
        handPath.lineTo(0.5f, 0.5f + 0.2f);
        handPath.addCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.025f, Path.Direction.CW);

        handScrewPaint = new Paint();
        handScrewPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        handScrewPaint.setColor(0xff493f3c);
        handScrewPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        backgroundPaint = new Paint();
        backgroundPaint.setFilterBitmap(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Width spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
        Log.d(TAG, "Height spec: " + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));

        int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
        int widthSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);

        int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int heightSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

        int chosenWidth = chooseDimension(widthMode, widthSize);
        int chosenHeight = chooseDimension(heightMode, heightSize);

        int chosenDimension = Math.min(chosenWidth, chosenHeight);

        setMeasuredDimension(chosenDimension, chosenDimension);
    }

    private int chooseDimension(int mode, int size) 
    {
        if (mode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST || mode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) 
        {
            return size;
        } 
        else 
        { // (mode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
            return getPreferredSize();
        }
    }

    // in case there is no size specified
    private int getPreferredSize() 
    {
        return 300;
    }

    private void drawScale(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        canvas.drawOval(scaleRect, scalePaint);

        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        for (int i = 0; i < totalNicks; ++i) 
        {
            float y1 = scaleRect.top;
            float y2 = y1 - 0.020f;
            canvas.drawLine(0.5f, y1, 0.5f, y2, scalePaint);
            if (i % 5 == 0) 
            {
                int value = nickToDegree(i);
                if (value >= minDegrees && value <= maxDegrees) 
                {
                    String valueString = Integer.toString(value);
                    canvas.drawText(valueString, 0.5f, y2 - 0.015f, scalePaint);
                }
            }
            canvas.rotate(degreesPerNick, 0.5f, 0.5f);
        }
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private int nickToDegree(int nick) 
    {
        int rawDegree = ((nick < totalNicks / 2) ? nick : (nick - totalNicks)) * 2;
        int shiftedDegree = rawDegree + centerDegree;
        return shiftedDegree;
    }

    private float degreeToAngle(float degree) 
    {
        return (degree - centerDegree) / 2.0f * degreesPerNick;
    }

    private void drawLogo(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.translate(0.5f - logo.getWidth() * logoScale / 2.0f,0.5f - logo.getHeight() * logoScale / 2.0f);
        int color = 0x00000000;
        float position = getRelativeTemperaturePosition();
        if (position < 0) 
        {
            color |= (int) ((0xf0) * -position); // blue
        } 
        else 
        {
            color |= ((int) ((0xf0) * position)) << 16; // red
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "*** " + Integer.toHexString(color));
        LightingColorFilter logoFilter = new LightingColorFilter(0xff338822,color);
        logoPaint.setColorFilter(logoFilter);

        canvas.drawBitmap(logo, logoMatrix, logoPaint);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private void drawHand(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        if (handInitialized) 
        {
            float handAngle = degreeToAngle(handPosition);
            canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
            canvas.rotate(handAngle, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            canvas.drawPath(handPath, handPaint);
            canvas.restore();
            canvas.drawCircle(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.01f, handScrewPaint);
        }
    }

    private void drawBackground(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        if (background == null) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Background not created");
        } 
        else 
        {
            canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, backgroundPaint);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        drawBackground(canvas);
        float scale = (float) getWidth();
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.scale(scale, scale);
        drawLogo(canvas);
        drawHand(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
        moveHand();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Size changed to " + w + "x" + h);
        regenerateBackground();
    }

    private void regenerateBackground() 
    {
        // free the old bitmap
        if (background != null) 
        {
            background.recycle();
        }

        background = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas backgroundCanvas = new Canvas(background);
        float scale = (float) getWidth();
        backgroundCanvas.scale(scale, scale);

    }

    private boolean handNeedsToMove() 
    {
        return Math.abs(handPosition - handTarget) > 0.01f;
    }

    private void moveHand() 
    {
        setHandTarget(maxDegrees);
        if (!handNeedsToMove()) 
        {
            return;
        }
        if (lastHandMoveTime != -1L) 
        {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float delta = (currentTime - lastHandMoveTime) / 1500.0f;
            float direction = Math.signum(handVelocity);
            if (Math.abs(handVelocity) < 90.0f) 
            {
                handAcceleration = 5.0f * (handTarget - handPosition);
            } 
            else 
            {
                handAcceleration = 0.0f;
            }
            handPosition += handVelocity * delta;
            handVelocity += handAcceleration * delta;
            if ((handTarget - handPosition) * direction < 0.01f * direction) 
            {
                handPosition = handTarget;
                handVelocity = 0.0f;
                handAcceleration = 0.0f;
                lastHandMoveTime = -1L;
            } 
            else 
            {
                Log.i("inside ","direction else loop");
                lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            invalidate();
        }   
        else 
        {
            Log.i("inside ","direction first final else loop");
            lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            moveHand();
        }
        if(handPosition==maxDegrees)
        {
            reverse();
        }
    }

    public void reverse()
    {
        handAcceleration=1.0f;
        Log.i("Hand Velocity",Float.toString(handVelocity));
        Log.i("Inside","next loop");
        setHandTarget(minDegrees);
        if (!handNeedsToMove()) 
        {
            return;
        }
        if (lastHandMoveTime != -1L) 
        {
            long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            float delta = (currentTime -lastHandMoveTime) / 1500.0f;
            float direction = Math.signum(handVelocity);
            if (Math.abs(handVelocity) <90.0f) 
            {
                handAcceleration = 5.0f * (handPosition+handTarget);
                Log.i("Hand Acceleration",Float.toString(handAcceleration));
            }       
            else 
            {
                handAcceleration = 0.0f;
            }   
            handPosition -= handVelocity * delta;
            handVelocity -= handAcceleration *delta;
            if ((handPosition + handTarget) * direction < 0.01f * direction) 
            {
                handPosition = handTarget;
                handVelocity = 0.0f;
                handAcceleration = 0.0f;
                lastHandMoveTime =-1L; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }   
            invalidate();
        } 
        else 
        {
            lastHandMoveTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            reverse();
        }   
    }

    private float getRelativeTemperaturePosition() 
    {
        if (handPosition < centerDegree) 
        {
            return -(centerDegree - handPosition)/ (float) (centerDegree - minDegrees);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return (handPosition - centerDegree)/ (float) (maxDegrees - centerDegree);
        }
    }

    private void setHandTarget(float temperature) 
    {
        if (temperature < minDegrees) 
        {
            temperature = minDegrees;
        } 
        else if (temperature > maxDegrees) 
        {
            temperature = maxDegrees;
        }
        handTarget = temperature;
        handInitialized = true;
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can anyone help you with what?  What are you stuck on?  What have you tried?  How to change the image?  How to rotate the needle?  How to change the image when the needle passes it?   All three?  What are you ideas for implementation?

Comment: I am completely lost as i don't have much knowledge of `Canvas` and `Animation`.But what i am thinking of is making use of threads and rotate it with degrees and when the needle reaches a particular degree where image is there i plan to change the bitmap.But don't know how to implement it. Plus the base of the needle should stay fix as the needle rotates.

Comment: OK, the best way to do this is to create a custom view by extending, for example, ImageView.  Then use the canvas to rotate an image which is your needle.  This should get you going http://mindtherobot.com/blog/272/android-custom-ui-making-a-vintage-thermometer/

Comment: i have seen this example. But then when i run the project i am not able to see the needle itself to see if there is any animation or not. 
But i am still trying to understand the code.

Comment: The reason you are not able to see the needle is because you probably don't have a temperature sensor. In the same code, file Thermometer.java, method attachToSensor change the "Sensor.TYPE_TEMPERATURE" to "Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD". You should then be able to see the needle.

Comment: @13hosj i tried it and it worked properly as i said in my above commment what my requirement is. i want the needle to move from start to the end and from end to start. i am able to succed with the first part but not able to do the other part.i am posting the code what i have done can u please help me

Answer (score 0):

Just initialize the hand position to max degree and in the `moveHand()` method `setHandTarget(minDegrees)` for anticlockwise rotation It worked for me.

For clockwise rotation just do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved hand showing and moving inserting this in main activity:

```
    View termometro = (View)findViewById(R.id.termometro);
    termometro.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

It has to do with hardware acceleration